# Coletando dados do Facebook com um Botao Compartilhar

Tags: java, android, facebook-sdk

Boa tarde!
Estou fazendo meu TCC e preciso de uma ajuda urgente! Por favor!

Seguinte... Estou fazendo meu app que no final da aplicação o usuário pode compartilhar, se quiser através de um shareDialog do face... até aí esta tranquilo... porém queria que quando o usuário clicasse em compartilhar... eu  conseguisse coletar os dados dele tais como: nome, sobrenome, idade, email e localização....
Preciso necessariamente fazer um botao login??
meu código está abaixo:

```
    public class CompartilharActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private ShareDialog shareDialog;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_compartilhar);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();



    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);  

}

public void shareLinks(View view) {

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.trofeu);
    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Nome")
                .setContentDescription("Descricao")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://site.com"))
                .build();


        shareDialog.show(content);
    }
}
```

Qual seria a melhor solução!
Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

Você só consegue pegar esses tipos de dados se caso o usuários permitir que esses dados sejam liberados. Para isso você precisa criar um `APP` no facebook pelo link: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ e depois criar uma solicitação de permissão ao usuário.

Veja esse exemplo pelo `SDK` em `PHP` do facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_batch_request

Dessa forma é criado um botão de permissão, onde o usuário precisa aceitar o que seu aplicativo está pedindo. Caso o usuário recuse, você não tem como obter esses dados.

Aqui você tem uma lista de permissões que você pode solicitar:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/